# Potential of Drupal 7 Calendar Module

Tags: drupal, calendar, drupal-7

I'm wanting to use the Drupal 7 Calendar Module to create a daily view of bookings for 4 different rooms.

I've never used the module before and I'm struggling to find any good tutorials or videos which do not need a subscription.

Can anyone who has used this tell me if this is possible?

I would have a booking node which is assigned with a taxonomy term. The booking would then show on the correct row, depending on which room it is in. Additional node fields would need to be shown when clicking the booking, and ideally contain a link to edit the booking. Does the module have the capacity to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar should be able to do this.  It won't handle all of the details of "booking" like available or not available, conflicts, etc.  You may need to override the calendar cell themeing to display things how you want depending on the desired complexity.  The "fields" display style should get you close.  You can use the "calendar popup" module (part of calendar) to customize the details when you click the booking.

Since you'll likely be using a date field in your booking content type, be sure and update default calendar views to use this field instead of the node's built in date.

Also, make sure you have time zone handling set up BEFORE you set up your calendar views and start entering data.  See: http://drupal.org/node/1455578

Comment: Good answer Chris. Just to check if I had a node with a room taxonomy term, and also multiple users referenced to it (Staff), then could I have a calendar showing each room per row and another calendar showing bookings for each staff member? IF a node references two users would the booking be shown on each users row as a duplicate instance?

Comment: You should be able to do that, yes.  To prevent duplicates you can add the "distinct" filter to the view.